# Rails Ajax submit doesn't work without reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form that is rendered via ajax and submitted via ajax.The problem I am facing is the ajax submit won't work on first submit but when the page is reloaded and the form is rendered for the second time the submit will work.

**The form**

```
   <%= form_for(@address,:remote=>true) do |f| %>
     <%= f.label :name %>
     <%= f.text_field :name %>
     <%= f.label :full_address %>
     <%= f.text_area :full_address %>
     <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**The controller method that handles save is**

```
def create
    @address = Address.new(address_params)
    @address.user_id=current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @address.save
        format.html { redirect_to @address, notice: 'Address was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @address }
        format.js 
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @address.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js 
      end
    end
  end
```

**Edit**
on the first XHR request I'm getting this for the form

```
<input name="utf8" value="✓" type="hidden">

  <div class="field">
    <label for="address_name">Name</label><br>
    <input name="address[name]" id="address_name" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="address_full_address">Full address</label><br>
    <textarea name="address[full_address]" id="address_full_address"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

However on the second request I'm getting this

```
<form class="new_address" id="new_address" action="/addresses" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
<input name="utf8" value="✓" type="hidden">

  <div class="field">
    <label for="address_name">Name</label><br>
    <input name="address[nEditame]" id="address_name" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="address_full_address">Full address</label><br>
    <textarea name="address[full_address]" id="address_full_address"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you get an exception when you press the button the first time?

Comment: In the first line of your form, the `<%=` should be a `<%`. Small error I noticed. Also, can you post your `address_params` method?

Comment: `user_params` or `address_params`. Substituting `<%` for `<%=`  didn't work.

Comment: can you please open DevTools or equivalent and check network activity when you press the submit?

Comment: @Kkulikovskis No network activity

Answer (score 1):

Your issue *sounds* like a JQuery delegation issue.

---

Most people bind JQuery to elements directly; this binding *only* happens on DOM load, meaning any new elements have no functions attached to them:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$("element").on("click"....
```

The above will only work if you have "element" defined at DOM load, and you invoke this function within the `$(document).ready` block.

--

If you have elements loaded *after* DOM load, you need to make sure your JQuery can bind to them. This used to be handled with [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) but is now done with [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", ".element"...
```

The above is used to bind events to elements loaded after the DOM. It *delegates* from the `document` object, which allows your JQuery to bind to any element you need.

In short, if you're working with ajax-loaded elements, you should always bind to the `document`, and delegate to the dynamic element.

---

**remote: true**

Since you're using `remote: true`, we have to look at how Rails handles the JS delegation.

As you can see from the [`rails.js` github page](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L428), it appears that Rails binds its event handlers through the `document`:

```
$document.delegate(rails.buttonClickSelector, 'click.rails', function(e) {
```

Whilst this seems okay, I would think that there is something preventing it from binding to your dynamically-loaded form.

---

## Fix

I would try this:

```
<%= form_for @address, id: "address" do |f| %>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("submit", "form#address", function(e){
   $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize());
});
```

The intention is to remove the `remote: true` reference, binding our own JS to the document & delegating to your dynamically loaded form.

It will still deliver an XHR request, thus maintaining the flow of your application.

Answer (score 0):

In your views for the controller  in question `addresses_controller`, create a new file called `create.js.erb`. This is where the response will be directed to.
In this file, write your jquery code

```
$('html_tag').html('<%=j render @address%>')
```

The view element that you want to replace should have a class,id or you can select it with the tag(

//...).

In case you are new to jquery, try this site .

[http://try.jquery.com/](http://try.jquer.com/)

Comment: Already I have a file it renders the second time but not for the first time